# Guzzle Post Request send file with additional param

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

I have problem with Guzzle sending post file. In API i have methoda with input like files (for file), name and isPublic. I dont know how to send these two additional param (filename and isPublic, maybe I understand multipart params in wrong way?

My example

```
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://www.example.com/files/post', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'files' - its input name in api for files?
            'contents' => fopen('path/to/file', 'r')
            'filename' => 'csv_header.csv'
//Should I add additional param name and isPublic in this array, or somewhere else? 
    ]]]
```

Please for advice. Thank You :)

Comment: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart

Comment: Fine, but there is info that each multipart array have following key (name, contest, headers, filename), so where should I add additional isPublic and name?